# Какой метод срабатывает у tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Какой метод срабатывает у tableView или cell в момент, когда нажимаешь на любое место на странице и свайпнутая до этого вправа ячейка возвращается на место. Интересует именно метод, который срабатывыает до возвращения ячейки на место.
По названиям ничего не подходит

Answer (score 1):

[tableView(_:didEndEditingRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614963-tableview)

**Исправление**

Встроенного метода определения начала выхода из режима редактирования насколько я знаю нет, однако можно добавить свой `UITapGestureRecognizer` и использовать его следующим образом, так как он срабатывает раньше вышеуказанного метода

```
// переменная класса
var tableViewIsEditing: Bool = false

let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableViewTap(sender:)))
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

@objc func tableViewTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if tableViewIsEditing {
        // производим действия
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableViewIsEditing = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        tableViewIsEditing = false
    }

}
```

Comment: это уже после возвращения ячейки, меня интересует до или во время